# generating power point files in angularJs 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, powerpoint

I have a requirement to create power-point files in my app written in Angular2, is there any library available to generate power point files for Angular2, I should be able to export data not only in power point format but even in PDF, Excel, should eb able to print the page or even generate visual board(something like canvas)

Comment: Using Google to search for Javascript libraries that do that is probably faster than asking on SO and waiting for people to do the searching for you, unless you're very lazy ;)

Comment: @rinukkusu: I have already google but might be google with wrong keywords, thanks with your advice, I need to google for javascript rather than angular, I thought they might be some angular wrapper for such functionalities which I could not found

Comment: Even then SO is not the right place to ask for software or libraries. But feel free to come back if you've found something and need help to make it work (after you've tried to solve it yourself first of course :) )!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pptxgenjs` from the link below:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/pptxgenjs/

Use `PPtxGenJs` in `angular2+` like this:

```
import * as pptGen from 'pptxgenjs';

const pptx = new pptGen();

const slide = pptx.addNewSlide();

slide.addImage({ data: 'image/png;base64, ' + b64Data + '', x: 1, y: 2, w: 3, h: 3 });

slide.addImage({ path: '/assets/mean.jpg', x: 1, y: 2, w: 3, h: 3 });

slide.addText('Image Path!', { x: 1.5, y: 1.5, font_size: 18, color: '363636' });

pptx.save('Sample Presentation');
```

This library has good options to create and modify slides.

Comment: Thanks @ngWolf, the reason I asked this question, at that time I was new to angular 2 and was working on angular 1 which usually we use wrapper libraries (to make it angular way) and I had the same though process for angular 2 that I might need a wrapper. Thanks for the suggestion